# load command from history but don't execute yet, so I can modify it

Tags: bash, command-history

In bash, I know how to

```
history |grep foo
```

which will give me a list of numbered commands from history containing foo. If I want to run one of those commands with a different argument, I can copy paste using the mouse. I don't want to repeat an exact command. I want to load it at the prompt and change something, then execute it. Is there a way to do so? Up arrow doesn't always work for me.

Comment: Is `CTRL+r` and then using the left/right arrow keys to edit parameters not an acceptable workflow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you’re using Bash, you can enable `histverify` and then recall commands with `!` followed by the command’s number in the history:

```
shopt -s histverify
```

Another interesting approach is to use `fc`:

```
fc 200
```

will load the 200th command in your history into your editor. You can then edit the command as you please, and it will be executed when you exit your editor.

Other shells such as Zsh have similar features.

See [the chapter on history interaction in the Bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/History-Interaction.html) for details.

Comment: Looks like shopt -s histverify works, but do you have to run it in every shell session you want to use it in, or does it persist until the hard drive is wiped?

Comment: You’d add it to your `.bashrc` typically.

Comment: does it replace `shopt -s histappend`, or is it used in addition?

Comment: In addition, both options control different history features.